# Display two side-by-side maps in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

Is there any way I can display two maps side by side on Google Earth Engine?

The same way leaflets can have a side-by-side plugin. Trying to find the widget to do so but can't find info.

Answer (score 4):

The [Earth Engine User Interface API](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/ui) allows you to replace the default map in the Code Editor with different things including multiple [maps](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/ui_widgets#ui.map), in [layouts including side by side](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/ui_panels) or [movable split to compare](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/ui_widgets#ui.splitpanel).

Comment: Thanks! But the movable split is still the same map, I am wondering if there is anyway I can copy the map and generate another exact one side by side?

Comment: @GaoleDal If you create two `ui.Map` widgets and don't link them then they are completely independent maps.

Comment: and is there a posibility so they would scroll and zoom to the same spot (like for example in SNAP)?